# updating table with data from different source

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to do the following:

```
update mytable 
set fullname = anothersource.firstname ||' '|| anothersource.lastname
where
userid = anothersource.userid
;
```

I am having errors which I am not pasting because it make not sense since I simplified the example, however, is there a special way of handling updates with information from different sources? I believe that may be where problem lives.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need a subquery for Oracle:

```
update mytable 
    set fullname = (select anothersource.firstname ||' '|| anothersource.lastname
                    from anothersource
                    where mytable.userid = anothersource.userid
                   );
```

If there is the danger that the subquery might return more than one row, then use an aggregation (such as `min()` or `where rownum = 1`).

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE mytable
SET  fullname =
     (SELECT firstname FROM anothersource WHERE user_id = user_id)
     ||' '||
     (SELECT lastname FROM anothersource1 WHERE user_id = user_id)
WHERE mytable_id = id;
```